# Tiles ViewPreparer defined in Spring not found by Tiles

Tags: spring, tiles

EDIT: *I believe it is the SpringBeanPreparerFactory property of tilesConfigurer that is responsible for making sure the preparers are available for tiles ... but it appears that it may not be working. The default for tilesConfigurer is "BasicPreparerFactory", and I see a reference to that in the server logs, I'm thinking that maybe somehow that property is not being set correctly and it's using the default, BasicPreparerFactor instead.*

I'm at a complete loss with this one... ANY thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

I am simply trying to use a Tiles ViewPreparer which is defined in my Spring configuration ... that's it! But for whatever reason, the "execute" method of my ViewPreparer is just never called. The ViewPreparer IS being constructed by Spring, and my tile is being rendered, but the preparer never executes. It's like there is a broken link between Tiles and Spring that should be there ... I say I'm using "testPreparer" in tiles.xml, which is a bean defined in "applicationContext.xml", but tiles is behaving like I didn't define a preparer at all. [Here's a good description of what I'm essentially trying to do.](http://pranav-varshney.blogspot.com/2009/04/struts-2-apache-tiles-view-preparer.html)

/WEB-INF/tiles.xml:

```
<tiles-definitions>

  <definition name="test.tile" template="testtile.jsp" preparer="testPreparer">
  </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
  <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
      <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="preparerFactoryClass"
      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringBeanPreparerFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="testPreparer" class="TestPreparer"></bean>
```

TestPreparer.java

```
import org.apache.tiles.AttributeContext;
import org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContext;
import org.apache.tiles.preparer.PreparerException;
import org.apache.tiles.preparer.ViewPreparer;


public class TestPreparer implements ViewPreparer {

    public void execute(TilesRequestContext arg0, AttributeContext arg1)
            throws PreparerException {
        System.out.println("I executed");

    }

}
```

struts.xml:

```
  <package name="apps-default" extends="struts-default"
    abstract="true">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles"
        class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
      </result-types>
    <interceptors>
      ...
    </interceptors>

   <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultAppStack"/>

  <package name="testPackage" extends="apps-default" namespace="/test">
    <action name="create" class="testAction" method="create">
      <result type="tiles">test.tile</result>
    </action>
  </package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. As it turns out, it was because I had the following entry in my web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

For whatever reason, that was essentially breaking/interfering with what I defined in applicationContext.xml. I'd have to do more investigation to figure out what exactly the conflict was, but needless to say removing that entry solved the issue.

Sorry, I spent the last 2 days trying to figure this out, and I guess writing my problem on here helped me think through it. Oh well, at least this will be documented out here on S.O. in case anyone else every runs into the same issue!